# How to make a table column that belongs to two row-colomns

Tags: tables

I have produced a table that looks like this:
[image]

I want to reproduce the table almost identical as the picture, but I have some difficulties. I used the following:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Type}}                   & \textbf{Model}                                                                                                                    & \textbf{Example}                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{A}                   & Belongs to A                                                                                                                         & Example 1                             \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{}                                     & \multirow{2}{*}{HERE IS PROBLEM}                                                                       & \multirow{2}{*}{PROBLEM} \\
                                                      &                                                                                                                                   &                                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{4}{*}{B}} & \begin{tabular}[c]   {@{}l@{}}Belongs to B\\  - \textit{Example1}\end{tabular} & Examples                               \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                & Belongs to B                                                                                                                   & Examples                  \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                & Belongs to B                                                                                                                    & Examples                           \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                & Belongs to B                                                                                                     & Examples                              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table problem}
\label{table123}
\end{table}
```

What I really want is the that 'A' and 'B' covers the cell with 'Belongs to A and B' , such that there is a overlap between A and B, as indicated in the figure.

Also, I would like to use:

```
\begin{enumerate} ... \end{enumerate}
```

in the table but did not succeed.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? I used the `makecell` package, which allows for line breaks in cells, and a common formatting of specific cells, with the commands `\makecell` and `\thead`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array, multirow, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering\setcellgapes[t]{3pt}\makegapedcells
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \thead{Type} & \thead{Model} & \thead{Example} \\ \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{A} & Belongs to A & Example 1 \\ \cline{2-3}
    & \raisebox{-1.5ex}[\height][0pt]{HERE IS PROBLEM} & \raisebox{-1.5ex}[\height][0pt]{PROBLEM} \\ \cline{1-1}
    \multirow{6}{*}[-1ex]{B} & & \\\cline{2-3}
   & \makecell[t]{Belongs to B \\ - \textit{Example1}} & Examples \\ \cline{2-3}
     & Belongs to B & Examples \\ \cline{2-3}
     & Belongs to B & Examples \\ \cline{2-3}
    & Belongs to B & Examples \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Table problem}
  \label{table123}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not really. I want the 'HERE IS PROBLEM' to be a part of both of 'A' and 'B', as indicated in my figure. So that means there is an overlap.

Comment: @André: I've modified (and simplified) the code. Is that nearer to what you want now?

Comment: I was indeed looking for that! 
Another questions: 'A' is not positioned at the centre of the cell, whereas 'B' is. How to fix this? Also, 'Belongs to B' - Example 1 is centrered in the cell. I want it to the left, just like the others. Any tips?

Comment: I'll fix that in a moment. For A, I didn't notice (it was centred in the first version). For ‘Belongs to B’, a s it resulted from your code, I thought it was intentional

Comment: Fixed! 'Twas enough to change the number of rows for 'A' and for the'Belongs to B', to use the optional position parameters of `\makecell` (the  default is `cc` – vertically and horizontally centred).